# Is There an Abel-plana-type Exact Formula for the Imaginary Part of the Oscillatory Integral over Exp(iπx)x^(1/x) Between 1 and Infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This is a question that is an important part of my life-long hobby of researching the [MRB constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MRBConstant.html).

CMRB [image: 2 forms of CMRB]

I have posted Mathematica code with all my formulas below.

Richard J. Mathar did in-depth research into [its Oscillatory Integral](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3844.pdf) (CMKB=M1).

[image: MATHAR]

On Feb 24, 2021, at 11:00 am EST I discovered the following Abel-Plana type integrals for the exact real value of M1 or ReMKB (Re[CMKB]),

[image: (f[(1-I t)] - f[( 1+I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] + 1),]

```
f[x_] = (-1)^x (x^(1/x) - 1); ReMKB = 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1-I t)] - f[( 1+I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] + 1), {t,
      0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]
```

(*0.070776039311528803539528021830282001365754696203363*)

and

[image: g[(1-t I)] - g[(1+t I)])/(2 Exp[Pi t]]

```
g[x_] = x^(1/x); ReMKB = 
N[I NIntegrate[(g[(1-t I)] - g[(1+t I)])/(2 Exp[Pi t] ), {t, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]
```

(* 0.070776039311528803539528021830282001365754696203363.*)

If you need an exact formula for the imaginary part, you can use

[image: I Sin[Pi n] g[n]]

Enter

```
g[x_] = x^(1/x); ImMKB = 
 N[NIntegrate[I Sin[Pi n] g[n], {n, 1, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100] - I/Pi, 50]
```

(*
0.*10^-51 - 0.68400038943793212918274445999266112671099148265500 I.*)

The imaginary part, along with the real part, can be computed to many digits through partial integration with formulas like the following.
[image]

```
 f[x_]:=x^(1/x);  Print[DateString[]]; Print[T0 = SessionTime[]]; prec =10000; 
  Timing[Print[
  a = N[Re[-(136584/Pi^10) - (34784*I)/Pi^9 + 
       5670/Pi^8 + (786*I)/Pi^7 - 90/Pi^6 - 
                 (4*I)/Pi^5 - 3/Pi^4 - (2*I)/Pi^3 + 
       1/Pi^2 - (2*I)/Pi] - 
             (1/Pi)^10*
      NIntegrate[Cos[Pi*x]*D[f[x], {x, 10}], {x, 1, Infinity}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> prec, 
                 PrecisionGoal -> prec], prec]]; 
 Print[SessionTime[] - T0, " seconds"]; 
     Print[
  N[b = -Im[-(136584/Pi^10) - (34784*I)/Pi^9 + 
        5670/Pi^8 + (786*I)/Pi^7 - 90/Pi^6 - 
                   (4*I)/Pi^5 - 3/Pi^4 - (2*I)/Pi^3 + 
        1/Pi^2 - (2*I)/Pi] + 
             (1/Pi)^10*
      NIntegrate[Sin[Pi*x]*D[f[x], {x, 10}], {x, 1, Infinity}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> prec, 
                 PrecisionGoal -> prec], prec]]]; Print[
 SessionTime[] - T0, " seconds"]; 
  Print[N[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], prec]]; Print[DateString[]];
```

**But is there an Abel-Plana-type exact formula for the imaginary part?**

P.s. when looking for one I made the following discovery at 1:15 am, March 6, 2021.

[image]

```
 f[x_] = (-1)^x (x^(1/x) - 1);

  CMRB = N[NSum[f[n], {n, 1, Infinity}, Method -> \
"AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]

 (* 0.18785964246206712024851793405427323005590309490014*)

 ReMKB = 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1 - I t)] - f[( 1 + I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] + 1), {t,
           0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]

 (*0.070776039311528803539528021830282001365754696203363*)

 NoMKB = 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1 - I t)] - f[( 1 + I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] - 1), {t,
           0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]

 (* 0.117083603150538316708989912223991228690148398696776*)

 ReMKB + NoMKB - CMRB

 (* 0.*10^-51*)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Some corrections made March 10, 2021.]

I found what I was looking for.

[image: ImMKB Abel]

```
g[x_] = x^(1/ x); ImMKB = -(N[
     I NIntegrate[(g[(1 - t I)] + g[(1 + t I)])/(2 Exp[Pi t]), {t, 0, 
        Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50] + I/Pi)
```

(*0.*10^-67 - 0.68400038943793212918274445999266112671099148265500 I. *)

In summary,

[image]

```
   In[149]:= f[x_] = (-1)^x (x^(1/x) - 1);

In[150]:= CMRB = N[NSum[f[n], {n, 1, Infinity}, Method -> \
"AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]

Out[150]= 0.18785964246206712024851793405427323005590309490014

In[151]:= ReMKB = 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1 - I t)] - f[( 1 + I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] + 1), {t,
           0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]

Out[151]= 0.070776039311528803539528021830282001365754696203363

In[261]:= ReMKB - 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1 - I t)] + f[( 1 + I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] - 1), {t,
           0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]

Out[261]= 0.*10^-51

In[152]:= NoMKB = 
 Im[N[NIntegrate[(f[(1 - I t)] - f[( 1 + I t)])/(Exp[2 Pi t] - 1), {t,
           0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]]

Out[152]= 0.117083603150538316708989912223991228690148398696776

In[153]:= ReMKB + NoMKB - CMRB

Out[153]= 0.*10^-51

In[171]:= g[x_] = x^(1/x);

In[195]:= MKB = 
 N[NIntegrate[Exp[I Pi t] g[t], {t, 1, 1 Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50] - I/Pi

Out[195]= 0.07077603931152880353952802183028200136575469620336 - 
 0.68400038943793212918274445999266112671099148265500 I

In[172]:= ImMKB = -(N[
     I NIntegrate[(g[(1 - t I)] + g[(1 + t I)])/(2 Exp[Pi t]), {t, 0, 
        Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50] + I/Pi)

Out[172]= 
0.*10^-67 - 0.68400038943793212918274445999266112671099148265500 I

In[162]:= ReMKB = 
 N[I NIntegrate[(g[(1 - t I)] - g[(1 + t I)])/(2 Exp[Pi t]), {t, 0, 
     Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], 50]

Out[162]= 0.070776039311528803539528021830282001365754696203363

In[196]:= ImMKB + ReMKB - MKB

Out[196]= 0.*10^-51 + 0.*10^-51 I
```